C# Postgres procedure with parameters
How do you call a pg procedure with parameters from C#?
I tried related examples and they did not work (i.e. this question)
Here is a super simple example:
Table:
    (col1 integer, 
    col2 character varying(20) )

Procedure:
    create procedure proc1 (num int, str varchar(20))
    language plpgsql    
    as $$
    begin  
    insert into test1 (col1, col2) VALUES (num, str);
    commit;
    end;$$;

Code where I attempt to use it:
    using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("CALL proc1()", _con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("num", NpgsqlDbType.Integer, 2);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("str", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, "string");

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Exception that I am getting:

Npgsql.PostgresException: '42883: procedure proc1() does not exist
POSITION: 6'

I also made a proc2 that has NO parameters and I'm able to call that one just fine.  I also tried several options to "CALL proc1()" like "CALL proc1(num, str)", but those exceptions make even less sense, as pg can't tell the difference between a parameter and a column:

Npgsql.PostgresException: '42703: column "num" does not exist


Parameters are prefixed with @

Don't assume that something used by thousands of developers doesn't work. Post enough SQL and C# code so others can reproduce the problem without making guesses. Their code and their procedures work with their versions of PostgreSQL and NpgSQL. The code you posted would never work because the call doesn't use any parameters. The error itself complains that the procedure doesn't exist, not about parameters.

Which versions of NpgSQL and PostgreSQL are you using?

I'm on the latest everything.  PG version 16.  npgsql 8.0.3
I added the prefix @ and that's still not enough to get this simplified hello world working.  I know people use this and my question is HOW?  don't assuming it can't work, condesending BS comments from Panagiotis NOT helpful 8===>

Try:
using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("proc1", _con);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("num", NpgsqlDbType.Integer, 2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("str", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, "string");

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Alternatively, you could use this syntax:
using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("CALL proc1($1, $2)", _con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("num", NpgsqlDbType.Integer, 2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("str", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, "string");

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#stored-functions-and-procedures

Have you tried upgrading? https://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/7.0.html#commandtypestoredprocedure-now-invokes-procedures-instead-of-functions

The first version works with a small modification of adding prefix @ on the params.  Thanks.
the second version is generating this error for me but I prefer the first anyways:
'08P01: bind message supplies 0 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 2'
